# Install a Rails gem of specific revision of a branch in Github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, version-control, github, rubygems

I updated a gem (ajaxful_rating), it breaks my code because of a new revision. How do I specify a particular revision to reinstall the gem?
I was trying:

```
gem 'ajaxful_rating', :git => 'git://github.com/edgarjs/ajaxful-rating.git', :branch => "rails3",
:revision =>'ecce22bf374caa328c087f3ca22711d1dd461906'
```

but it didn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: If you are looking for the latest version then you simply need to write gem 'ajaxful_rating'. You might also want to delete gemfile.lock before doing bundle install

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use the `:ref => hashnumber`. Only one option between `:branch`, `:ref`, and `:tag` can be used. As usual, the answer was in the man : http://gembundler.com/man/gemfile.5.html

You will probably have to `bundle update ajaxful_rating` after that.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to drop the :branch from your Gemfile.

```
gem 'ajaxful_rating', :git => 'git://github.com/edgarjs/ajaxful-rating.git', :ref => 'ecce22bf374caa328c087f3ca22711d1dd461906'
```

The branch is implicit because commit 'ecce22b' only exists on the rails3 branch.

Comment: The "branch" is *not* implicit. It's meaningless. The commit ID is globally unique within the repository, regardless of the branch. It identifies a specific version of the files and "branch" is not a relevant concept in that scenario.

Comment: @Romain I don't disagree with any of that.  Thanks for the correction.